# calculate combinations ratios in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, combinations

I'm trying to calculate combinations ratios in a data frame column which contains multiple samples columns, I have over 60k values(rows) for each column, and I would like to calculate the ratios combinations for each two values in each column. I start with an empty data frame and add the ratio in each iteration.

this is the code I've got so far:

```
non_norm_data = data.values.T  # turns df into numpy array, row = sample, column = feature\value  
df_for_pairwise_ratio = pd.DataFrame()  
numerators_df = pd.DataFrame()  
for subject in range(np.shape(non_norm_data)[0]):  # run on subjects number
    subject_values = non_norm_data[subject, :]
    for idx, (feature1, feature2) in enumerate(product(non_norm_data[subject, :],              non_norm_data[subject, 1:])):  
        big_small_pair = max(feature1, feature2),\
            min(feature1, feature2)  # the first one is the bigger value
        ratio = big_small_pair[0] / big_small_pair[1]

        df_for_pairwise_ratio.loc[idx, f"Subject {subject}"] = ratio
        numerators_df.loc[idx, f"Subject {subject}"] = big_small_pair[0]
```

This takes a long time and I'm having memory errors, is there any way to makes this more efficient?
this is a small section of my data:

```
  0        1     2     3
40.96  50.19  30.46 33.17
118.71 55.55  43.56 142.89 
22.67  102.33 8.48  14.56
```

Thank you!

Comment: Normally iteration is not needed in Pandas. Please share a sample of your data

Comment: 0            1             2             3             4
40.96 50.19 30.46 33.17 118.71
55.55 43.56 142.89 22.67 102.33
8.48         14.56 99.13 15.55 15.47
10.91 9.22 22.29 15.51 14.33
4695.19 1652.19 22.53 49.02 956.48
2290.92 1437.86 38.39 156.32 1326.6
25302.97 13794.68 211.89 6933.64 34127.15
110.54    46.46  177.52    44.95    96.42
30133.43 17005.9 12992.94 14702.53 3466.81

Comment: It is not readable this way. Please add it formatted in your question above

Comment: `non_norm_data` is two-dimensional, so your sample data also need to be shown as two-dimensional

Comment: I tried adding it to my question, each number (0,1,2,3) is the column header and each one has different values, I would like to calculate the ratios for each columns combination

Comment: When you write `non_norm_data[subject, 1:]`, what purpose is it for? If it's to avoid self-ratios (1), that's not enough.

Answer (score 2):

Vectorization needed. First construct a high-dimensional pair array (avoiding self-reference), sort, and then vectorized-divide.

```py
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


with StringIO("""
     0       1      2      3
 40.96   50.19  30.46  33.17
118.71   55.55  43.56 142.89 
 22.67  102.33   8.48  14.56""") as f:
    data = pd.read_fwf(f)
print(data)

# Make a 3x3x4x2 matrix:
# numerator row, by denominator row, by subject, by numerator-or-denominator
pair_stack = np.stack(
    np.broadcast_arrays(
        data.values[:, np.newaxis, :],
        data.values[np.newaxis, :, :],
    ),
    axis=-1,
)

# Lower-triangular index avoiding self-reference via k=-1 (remove ratio=1 outputs).
# This produces a 3x4x2 matrix.
pairs = pair_stack[np.tril_indices(pair_stack.shape[0], k=-1)]

# Put the denominator first and numerator second on the last axis.
pairs.sort(axis=-1)

# Transpose and unpack to separate denominator and numerator arrays, each 3x4.
denominator, numerator = np.transpose(pairs, (2, 0, 1))

df_for_pairwise_ratio = pd.DataFrame(
    data= numerator / denominator,
    columns=pd.Index(
        name='Subject', data=data.columns,
    ),
)
print(df_for_pairwise_ratio)

# Same as old output, but without ratio=1 rows
with StringIO("""
Subject 0  Subject 1  Subject 2  Subject 3
 2.898193   1.106794   1.430072   4.307808
 1.806793   2.038852   3.591981   2.278159
 5.236436   1.842124   5.136792   9.813874
""") as f:
    expected_df = pd.read_fwf(f)
assert np.allclose(expected_df.values, df_for_pairwise_ratio.values)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm trying to implement this on my data and understand, what is the purpose of pair_stack ? with this data I provided here i get the first row values twice in two separate columns

Comment: The duplication is deliberate. Between indices 0 and 1 of the last dimension, the arrays are an exact copy of each other, just transposed. The duplication isn't removed until you triangular-index.